# Stage will not close with BorderPane after phone is rotated 90 degrees

Tags: javafx, gluon, borderpane

I believe I've found a bug with BorderPane.  The stage will close as expected if you do not rotate the phone.   However, if you rotate the phone and then click on Close the screen does nothing until you rotate the phone back to the original position and then is displays the primaryStage.   The code to recreate it is very simple.

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.event.EventHandler;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.FlowPane;
import javafx.stage.Modality;
import javafx.stage.Screen;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class HelloWorld extends Application {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        primaryStage.setTitle("Hello World!");
        Button btn = new Button();
        btn.setText("Say 'Hello World'");
        btn.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {

            @Override
            public void handle(ActionEvent event) {
                final Stage stage = new Stage();

                Button closeBtn = new Button("Close");
                closeBtn.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {
                    @Override
                    public void handle(ActionEvent event) {
                        stage.close();
                    }
                });
                FlowPane pane = new FlowPane();
                pane.getChildren().addAll(new Label("Hello World!"), closeBtn);
                Scene scene = new Scene(pane);
                stage.initModality(Modality.APPLICATION_MODAL);
                stage.initOwner(primaryStage);
                stage.setScene(scene);
                stage.show();
            }
        });

        BorderPane borderPane = new BorderPane();
        borderPane.setPrefHeight(Screen.getPrimary().getVisualBounds().getMaxY());
        borderPane.setPrefWidth(Screen.getPrimary().getVisualBounds().getMaxX());
        borderPane.setCenter(btn);

        primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(borderPane));
        primaryStage.show();
    }
```

Does anyone know how to work around this issue?

build.gradle

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'org.javafxports:jfxmobile-plugin:1.0.8'
    }
}

apply plugin: 'org.javafxports.jfxmobile'

mainClassName = 'helloworld.HelloWorld'
version = '8u40'

repositories {
    mavenLocal()
    mavenCentral()
    jcenter()
}

jfxmobile {
    ios {
    forceLinkClasses = ['ensemble.**.*']
    }
    android {
    applicationPackage = 'org.javafxports.ensemble'
    }
}
```

Thank you for the hints.   I removed the extra stage and scene.    My workaround is this.

```
package helloworld;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.event.EventHandler;
import javafx.scene.Group;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.FlowPane;
import javafx.stage.Screen;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class HelloWorld extends Application {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        primaryStage.setTitle("Hello World!");

        final Group group = new Group();

        final BorderPane borderPane = new BorderPane();
        borderPane.setPrefHeight(Screen.getPrimary().getVisualBounds().getMaxY());
        borderPane.setPrefWidth(Screen.getPrimary().getVisualBounds().getMaxX());

        final Button btn = new Button("Say 'Hello World'");
        borderPane.setCenter(btn);
        btn.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {

            @Override
            public void handle(ActionEvent event) {
                Button closeBtn = new Button("Close");
                closeBtn.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {
                    @Override
                    public void handle(ActionEvent event) {
                        group.getChildren().setAll(borderPane);
                    }
                });
                FlowPane pane = new FlowPane();
                pane.getChildren().addAll(new Label("Hello World!"), closeBtn);
                group.getChildren().setAll(pane);
            }
        });

        group.getChildren().add(borderPane);

        primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(group));
        primaryStage.show();
    }
}
```

Comment: What phone?  You might want to provide some more info on how you tested this.  Whatever the issue is, it would seem unlikely to be a bug in BorderPane as you suggest in the question.

Comment: Make: LG Model: LGMS330 Hardware version: Rev. 1.0

Comment: Android Version: 5.1.1 patch level 2015-12-01 Kernel version 3.10.49

Comment: Are you using JavaFXPorts? Are you using the Gluon plugin to create the project? Can you post your `build.gradle` file?

Answer (score 0):

While I can reproduce your issue, and you can report it [here](https://bitbucket.org/javafxports/javafxmobile-plugin/issues?status=new&status=open), on mobile things are a little bit different from desktop, and you shouldn't create a different stage or a different scene: just switch the nodes on the scene instead.

If you create the project with Gluon's plugin, you'll notice it uses `View` nodes, and you can easily switch between them, but always related to the same root (`GlassPane`) on the same scene.

If you need dialogs, you can use JavaFX built-in Dialogs, but Gluon already has its own dialogs, more adapted to a mobile environment.